# Adding dynamic control with animation

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've got this function:

```
void Title(string t)
    {
        if (called == true)
        {
            GrdLogo.Children.Remove((TextBlock)GrdLogo.FindName("Tb"));

        }

            TextBlock Tb = new TextBlock();
            Tb.Text = t;
            Tb.Name = "Tb";


            Tb.Height = 160;
            Tb.FontSize = 70;
            Tb.Margin = new Thickness(Img.Width * 2 + 30, 30, 0, 0);
            GrdLogo.Children.Add(Tb);

    }
```

And after calling this function I get error:

> WinRT information: The name already exists in the tree: Tb.

Xaml code of thisGrid (GrdLogo):

```
<Grid x:Name="GrdLogo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="160" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366" Background="#FF1D1D1D">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    </Grid>
```

Additionally, without transistion it works but I don't know how it can make any difference so I'm asking for help. I'm still pretty fresh in creating dynamic controls. Anyway for me code looks good but maybe I should use some kind of async method to delete this TextBlock?

Comment: Should we assume you are actually setting "called=true" as needed?

Comment: Yeah, there's no doubt. I tested it many times and without transition in Grid it works well. The point is how to run this with transition without using global int types couse I think it isn't necesserly.

Comment: Are you sure `GrdLogo.FindName("Tb")` return non-null value?

Comment: Yeah, as I said whenn im not using transition it works well but with no animations. Ill check it one more time just for sure.

Comment: I've just tested it one more time... no transition=no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears because `GrdLogo` instance doesn't know you removed element named `Bd` from it's visual tree. You need to notify it by calling `FrameworkElement.UnregisterName`:

```
if (called == true)
{
    GrdLogo.Children.Remove((TextBlock)GrdLogo.FindName("Tb"));
    GrdLogo.UnregisterName("Tb");
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you cannot use that method in your W8 code (there is no namescope access in WinRT), you should avoid using named elements altogether. Remove your textblock name in xaml and use other means of removing control like:

```
GrdLogo.Children.Remove(GrdLogo.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().Single());
```

Comment: Seems that this is solution but my compiler don't recognize "unregisterName" (VS 2012 for W8) even if i place using System.Windows on the begining (as far as i know it's namespace where unregistername is). Then what do i need to do to use this method?

Comment: @MajQel It seems this method is only present in WPF. I've searched WinRT documentation and found no method to unregister name from namescope.

Comment: So I cannot unregister it if im not using wpf?? thats bad ;/

Comment: Thank you very much :)
This was pretty easy but i'm sitting on this app more tan 5 hours so can't think straight :s
One more time thx.